# Availability of IP Address - Python

Tags: python, networking, ip-address, static-ip-address

How to check the availability of an IP address in python?

For example, I wan't to change my system's IP address to 192.168.112.226 statically overriding the dhcp provided address. The default gateway is 192.168.112.1. But I wan't to check before if anyone is using 192.168.112.226 before assigning to myself.

Usually do this in command line from bash. I check with ping 192.168.112.226. If host is unreachable, I use 'ifconfig' and 'route' to assign it to myself.

How to automate this using python?

PS: I prefer python so that I can use python-notify to beautify the output whether success or failure.

Comment: You need to install a DHCP server on your network.

Comment: I don't want to assign using dhcp. DHCP is already available. But I want to assign a static IP to my system overriding the one provided by DHCP. But before overriding I want to ensure it is not assigned to any other system in the network. And I don't want to use ping. There should some way where this can be found out programmatically.

Comment: I'm curious what the reason is?

Comment: @Keith I don't know whether ping is reliable. Check Hugh Bothwell's comment below.

Comment: This is impossible.  The machine using the IP might be turned off.  Ping tells you if a machine using the address happens to be online, not whether the address is already used.

Comment: @Bharat But then the DHCP server won't know that you took it, and may try to assign it some somebody else later. Unless you're using an IP in a range that it doesn't serve.

Comment: @Keith Just now saw this comment. So it concludes that this is not possible without the server support?!

Comment: @Bharat it's possible but you may cause problems for somebody (and yourself). There are a couple of legitimate ways to do this, but may or may not work depending on how the DHCP server is configured. 1) ask sysadmin for persistent IP address for you. 2) supply hostname in DHCP request. If server supports dynamic DNS they your name will appear in the DNS, which remains constant. You always refer to your host by name, so changing IP address won't matter.

Comment: @Keith Can you elaborate on how to do 2? Is it possible via bash or python?

Comment: @Bharat that's your DHCP client config. for dhcpcd set `hostname` in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: @Keith Ok. I could not find /etc/dhcpcd.conf but I do find /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf
Here I've set 
send host-name "bharath-laptop";

So if I assign statically using ifconfig will it update dhcp-server?

Answer (score 1):

This is so bad in so many ways I can't even explain how awfull this is.

Why do you want this?  Could you please tell us that, and we could come up with a much better answer than this utterly uggly "sollution"?

If you have a Linux/Unix system, you can make your DHCP client to request the DHCP-server to give you a specific IP address if the DHCP server know it's free. How to do this depends on the distribution.

There are two problems I see that you will create with your "sollution".

- As some other has written, you could check to see that the IP is "free" right now, but the machine that own that IP address might start right after your test. Using its IP address, wich you have kidnapped.
- If the DHCP server don't know that you have kidnapped an IP address, it could give it out to someone else.

Whatever it will break the network for that computer and yours, generating lots of work, and possible anger for/to the network administrator. And you don't want that, do you?

Comment: I perfectly understand your point of view but I suppose that he's trying this at home with his adsl router just for the sake of fun and learning python.
I suppose :)

Comment: Pitto, even though this use are really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you want to use bash, you can import os module or subprocess module.

for example:

```
import os
command = os.system('pint 192.168.112.226')
if command == 0: #Sucess
    #write os.system() and give it ifconfig and route commands as parameter.
else: print "This IP is used by another person in your network."
```

you can read more about os.system and subprocess in python, by importing them and writing `help(subprocess)` for example.

Comment: I don't want to use ping. It will never come out.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this method. One is the ping command as given never ends. You need to limit the number of pings with the -c option `ping -c 1 192.168.112.226`. ON Unix, the system command does not just return the errorlevel, but a packed return value with status and reason. You must unpack it like this: `rv = WEXITSTATUS(os.system(cmd)) == 0`

Comment: @Keith It should be os.WEXITSTATUS. This is the best solution so far. Thank you!

Comment: Some computers will have ICMP disabled, ie will not respond to ping; some computers may be temporarily offline. The general best solution to this problem is DHCP.

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell I have DHCP server in my network. I don't have access to it. But many times it provides different IP address to my system. I want my IP address to be consistent. So I want to manually reassign it.

Comment: @Bharat did you try asking your sysadmin if they can assign a permanent IP to your host in the DHCP server? That is possible to do.

Comment: @Keith No. This is out of my personal interest. I can't access the DHCP Server.

Comment: @Bharat but the sysadmin can access it. Also, this doesn't make much sense since you want a permanent IP, but if the one you pick is already taken you'll have to change it yourself, anyway. So it's not permanent. Frankly, it's also being a bad network citizen. Some sysadmin may have to spend time tracking you down at some point...

Comment: @Keith Yes. I understand that it is not advisable to assign static ip. That is why I want to be cautious to know if anyone is using. I know that we can make the dhcp server assign a static address for a particular mac address. But no. The sysadmin will not encourage to do that. Basically cannot access dhcp server :(

Comment: Little googling led me to two commands, nmap and arp. Still don't know whether they are reliable!

Comment: @Bharathwaaj, I would not encourage this for the reasons that other posters have stated. But, on Linux you can ping the host and then check ARP to see if there is an entry in the table. If there is an ARP entry, you can be sure that someone else is using the IP address - even if the ping didn't respond. Try the ping command for the IP address you are interested in, then `cat /proc/net/arp | tail --lines=+2 | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep ^192.168.112.226$` (use the IP address you are interested in in the `grep` command, of course). If it prints out an IP address, it is in use.

Comment: @Mike i think the last line should be "if it doesn't print out an IP address, it is in use". I checked it just now.

Comment: @Bharathwaaj, did you ping the host first? Try just `cat /proc/net/arp`. This will list all the hosts on your network that you have recently communicated with. For example, your default router should *always* be in that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket.gethostbyaddr() to find if IP Address is being in use or not.

```
import sys, os, socket

# Stores the IP Address
ip_address = sys.argv[1]

try:
    socket.gethostbyaddr(ip_address)
    # If previous line doesn't throw exception, IP address is being used by someone
    print "No"
except socket.herror:
    # socket.gethostbyaddr() throws error, so IP is not being used at present
    # You can write os.system() and give it ifconfig and route commands as parameter.
    print "Yes"
```

The problem with this code is that method.gethostbyaddr() takes lot of time to throw socket.herror if IP address is not in use on the network.

If you name this script as *isIPAvailable.py*, then it can be called by:

```
python isIPAvailable.py 192.168.112.226
```

Comment: I don't know whether this approach is correct. Because I just now found an issue with this. I'll give the steps to reproduce. First the dhcp server assigned 192.168.112.143 to my system. I then overrode it with ifconfig to 192.168.112.226. Now if i check python isIPAvailable.py 192.168.112.143, it is telling not available.

Comment: @Bharathwaaj I did the same thing just now, but it worked. Did you ping 192.168.112.143 after overriding your IP address with 192.168.112.226?

Comment: Yes. Basically after I reassign to 192.168.112.226, 192.168.112.142 should be available.